# What is the second word after the 「リミット」 and what is モノ(there is an image)

Tags: translation, meaning

[image]

About the second word after 「リミット」. I guess that it's a museum, but then the question is: How can be linked the word "limit" and "museum". Is it just "limit-museum" (but it's sounds a little strange)? And what is モノ and how to use it when I'm translating? Thanks for answer!

Answer (score 1):

That is:

リミット資料館{しりょうかん}~絵{え}を[描]{えが}くときに役立{やくだ}っているモノたち~

資料館 means indeed museum, reference library, archive.
The second part of the the sentence I think could be translated as "useful things　when drawing a picture/making a painting". That モノ is indeed 物　and probably is in katakana to put emphasis on that word (in Japanese often katakana is used in that way).

As for limit yes, I don't know the context but it seems indeed just the name of the place.

Comment: I just updated the answer a bit.　Just noticed that my edit is wrong have to re-edit..Sorry about that.

Comment: In the beginning I said I wasn't sure if there was the small つ but it has to be there because of the い... If it was in potential form it would have been やくだてる.

Comment: How do you know "リミット = limit" from the given context?

Comment: I don't indeed, as I said. However, do you know any other translation for リミット other than "limit"?

Comment: Just wanted to point out that the phrase「絵を描く」is almost always read えをかく, not えをえがく. However the word 描く by itself can be either かく or えがく.

Answer (score 0):

I'll just say "Limit museum" as it's just a name. As for モノ, it's the same word as 物 but it sounds a bit more "likable" or kind of cute if that makes sense.

Comment: Hm, then it turns out "Limit museuml; If you will use this a cute thing(when you're painting) it will be helpful for you" Something like this? Or how? Thanks for your answer!